# Как реализовать Inversion of Control в Rust?

Tags: архитектура, rust, solid, inversion-of-control

Здравствуйте.
Я потихоньку осваиваю раст, и решил по ходу писать на нем небольшое приложение, чтобы лучше понять принципы разработки на нем. Проблема у меня возникла буквально сразу. Возьмем для примера вот такую сферическую архитектуру в вакууме, без характерных расту усложнений:

```
trait Some {
  fn get_id(&self) -> int;
}

trait SomeFactory {
  fn create_some(&self) -> &Some
}

struct MyApp {
  factory: &SomeFactory
}

impl MyApp {
  fn new(f: &SomeFactory) -> MyApp {
    MyApp {
      factory: f
    }
  }
}
```

Без IoC контейнера я могу сделать что-то в этом роде:

```
fn bootstrap() -> MyApp {
  let factory = MyFactory::new();
  MyService::new(&factory)
}

fn main() {
  let app = bootstrap();
  app.run();
}
```

Но, естественно, я не хочу, чтобы при каждом изменении списка параметров в ::new мне приходилось лезть в bootstrap и вручную переделывать инициализацию приложения. Вот, чего я хочу добиться:

```
fn bootstrap() -> IoC {
  let IoC = IoC::new();
  IoC.Register<SomeFactory, MyFactory>();
  IoC.Register<SomeApp, MyApp>();

  IoC
}

fn main() {
  let IoC = bootstrap();
  let app = IoC.Resolve<SomeApp>();
  app.run();
}
```

В принципе, не важно макрос это будет, или нет. Хотя, реализация, которая будет работать во время компиляции а не выполнения даже предпочтительнее.

Есть ли уже какие-нибудь практики, или, может быть, идеи, как это лучше делать в расте?

Comment: Начнём с того, что вот так:
`
fn bootstrap() -> MyApp {
  let factory = MyFactory::new();
  MyService::new(&factory)
}
` сделать нельзя, потому что непонятно кто будет владеть factory, у вас будет ошибка времени жизни (MyService переживает factory).

Comment: Мне кажется, тут проще смотреть в сторону https://aturon.github.io/ownership/builders.html

Comment: @ozkriff, билдер используется, когда параметры объекта определяются контекстом. Если и говорить о паттернах, здесь куда лучше подошла бы фабрика. Их, в общем то, в таких случаях и используют, если нет возможности сделать что-то по-лучше. Но ведь здравомыслящий человек не будет пропихивать фабрики через всё приложение, если нет необходимости создания объекта, не связанного временем жизни с контекстом.

Comment: Боюсь, фабрика так себе (как минимум по мнению сообщества) вписывается в филосовию Ржавчины. Нагуглилась еще вот такая ссылка: https://github.com/jdavis/rust-design-patterns/blob/master/patterns/abstract_factory.rs - вдруг поможет.

Comment: @ozkriff, боюсь, это как раз то, о чем я говорил выше. Да, это может быть приемлемым решением, если язык не позволяет реализовать IoC. Но я уверен, что в расте это возможно ) Во-первых есть мощная система расширений компилятора, которая пока не входит в релизы, но, если там есть возможность получить доступ к AST имплементации, очень даже сгодится для IoC уже на стадии компиляции. Во-вторых есть std::reflect и std::repr, которые, вроде как, умеют получать метаданные во время выполнение, чего тоже может быть достаточно для реализации IoC.

Comment: кину еще на всякий: http://keepcalmandlearnrust.com/2016/08/implementing-an-object-factory-pattern-in-rust-using-closures/

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/9mdp8c/whats_everyone_working_on_this_week_412018/e7krrp6/ - вот еще ссылка, вдруг кому поможет